AWS CodePipeline ListBucket permissions error
I am defining a Code Pipeline via CDK. The final stage deploys a lambda cloudformation stack however I get an S3 permissions error when the deploy stage runs.
The deploy stage is defined as:
const role = new Role(this, "Role", {
    roleName: "CodePipelineBuildAndDeployRoleV2",
    description:
        "role used by code pipeline to build CDK and lambda application code",
    managedPolicies: [
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AWSCodePipeline_FullAccess"),
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("AmazonS3FullAccess"),
        ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName(
            "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess"
        ),
    ],
    assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal("codebuild.amazonaws.com"),
});

const pipeline = new Pipeline(this, "PipelineStack", {
    pipelineName: "LambdaDeploymentPipeline",
    pipelineType: PipelineType.V2,
    role: role,
});

//...source and build stage run correctly

pipeline.addStage({
    stageName: "Deploy",
    actions: [
        new CloudFormationCreateUpdateStackAction({
            actionName: "lambda-application-deployment",
            stackName: props.lambdaApplicationStack.stackName,
            templatePath: cdkBuildOutput.atPath("LambdaStack.template.yaml"),
            adminPermissions: true,
        }),
    ],
});


the error is:
User: arn:aws:sts::975050149793:assumed-role/CodePipelineStack-PipelineStackDeploylambdaapplicat-gF0oLczc8T7Z/1726918379606 is not authorized to perform: s3:ListBucket on resource: "arn:aws:s3:::codepipelinestack-pipelinestackartifactsbucket870a-z0ggjsmh1utz" because no session policy allows the s3:ListBucket action (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;

however when I check the permissions policy for the created role arn:aws:sts::975050149793:assumed-role/CodePipelineStack-PipelineStackDeploylambdaapplicat-gF0oLczc8T7Z/1726918379606
in the IAM console I can see it has list bucket permissions on the given bucket:
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Action":[
        "s3:Abort*",
        "s3:DeleteObject*",
        "s3:GetBucket*",
        "s3:GetObject*",
        "s3:List*",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:PutObjectLegalHold",
        "s3:PutObjectRetention",
        "s3:PutObjectTagging",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging"
      ],
      "Resource":[
        "arn:aws:s3:::codepipelinestack-pipelinestackartifactsbucket870a-z0ggjsmh1utz",
        "arn:aws:s3:::codepipelinestack-pipelinestackartifactsbucket870a-z0ggjsmh1utz/*"
      ],
      "Effect":"Allow"
    },
    {
      "Action":[
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:DescribeKey",
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*"
      ],
      "Resource":"arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:975050149793:key/cc2ef46c-329f-4e44-b209-89c7cce97cf4",
      "Effect":"Allow"
    },
    {
      "Action":[
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
        "ecr:PutImage",
        "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
      ],
      "Resource":"arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:975050149793:repository/hello-world-ecr-repository-from-cdk",
      "Effect":"Allow"
    },
    {
      "Action":"ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
      "Resource":"*",
      "Effect":"Allow"
    },
    {
      "Action":"sts:AssumeRole",
      "Resource":[
        "arn:aws:iam::975050149793:role/CodePipelineStack-PipelineStackBuildcdkcodesynthesi-CBELbize1taP",
        "arn:aws:iam::975050149793:role/CodePipelineStack-PipelineStackBuildlambdadockerima-022VbTwX3Bwh",
        "arn:aws:iam::975050149793:role/CodePipelineStack-PipelineStackDeploylambdaapplicat-gF0oLczc8T7Z",
        "arn:aws:iam::975050149793:role/CodePipelineStack-PipelineStackSourceCDKGitHubSourc-YLxuCRQKhqOD",
        "arn:aws:iam::975050149793:role/CodePipelineStack-PipelineStackSourceLambdaGitHubSo-aOOfOJyDHRhJ"
      ],
      "Effect":"Allow"
    }
  ]
}

what updates do I need to make to rectify this error?
Update:
@Clinton suggested granting explicit bucket permission.
I tried adding both of these policies (from the bucket as well as directly to the role):
        pipeline.artifactBucket.grantReadWrite(
            role
        )
        role.addToPolicy(new PolicyStatement(
            {
                actions: ['s3:ListBucket'],
                resources: [pipeline.artifactBucket.bucketArn]
            }
        ))

but got the same error message:
User: arn:aws:sts::975050149793:assumed-role/CodePipelineBuildAndDeployRoleV2/1727281876060 is not authorized to perform: s3:ListBucket on resource: "arn:aws:s3:::codepipelinestack-pipelinestackartifactsbucket870a-bfyw12hchv0e" because no session policy allows the s3:ListBucket action (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: WQR9HYW9YNR1ZM3M; S3 Extended Request ID: YWFHapGzf+jMe90dHP7/sVhdYlwrBo26Y0faumzuaqbarFyb+rbzqp6TL0cVKoRXOuWFLKyaXVv90T6q1hNQ6g==; Proxy: null)


Is this a cross-account stack?

What region are you deploying from and is the bucket defined in? Are they the same?

No they’re not cross account. And all resources are in us-east-1

Verify KMS key used by CodePipeline to encrypt artifact and compare it to the one you have in assumed role policy

ListBucket operates at the bucket level, not the object level; this is actually a common miss.
Modify the policy for the IAM role to add explicit permission for s3:ListBucket on the bucket itself like this:
{
      "Action": "s3:ListBucket",  
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::codepipelinestack-pipelinestackartifactsbucket870a-z0ggjsmh1utz",
      "Effect": "Allow"
},

It needs to target the bucket itself without the wildcard '/*'. Let me know if this works.

I have given this a try via
            {
                actions: ['s3:ListBucket'],
                resources: [pipeline.artifactBucket.bucketArn]
            }
        ))


Did that work? If not, could you share the error message?

unfortunately that didn't work - I updated the question wit those changes. Please lmk if there is more info I can provide

The original code already grants s3:List* on the bucket level.

@219CID I can see a difference in the updated error, it's not the same role. Without looking at the rest of the code it looks like the deploy stage is running under a different role? Confirm which role is being assumed in the deploy stage and then apply ListBucket permission.

The first error you listed says the role without permission is
CodePipelineStack-PipelineStackDeploylambdaapplicat-gF0oLczc8T7Z

...while the error you listed in your update says the role without permission is
CodePipelineBuildAndDeployRoleV2

Which role are you assuming?  You said you "got the same error" but it is not actually the same error.  Check that the role you are using has the ListBucket permission.  Also check if there is a resource policy on the bucket that would be limiting things, and if so, change that.  If you still get an error, try assigning the AmazonS3FullAccess or AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess managed policy temporarily to help isolate where the error is coming from, then remove/replace policies until you narrow it down.

This is likely due to the fact that your bucket is encrypted with a KMS key, and none of the identity policies in the role allow KMS actions.
Option 1:
Omit the role altogether and let CDK manage the permissions for you - it should be smart enough to grant the necessary ones automatically.
Option 2:
Since you're already granting very broad permissions to the role, you can add a policy statement granting KMS actions on all keys in your account:
role.addToPolicy(
  new iam.PolicyStatement({
    actions: [
      "kms:ReEncrypt*",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
      "kms:Encrypt",
      "kms:DescribeKey",
      "kms:Decrypt",
    ],
    resources: ["*"],
  }),
);

